# Apache limit connections

Tags: apache-2.2

how do I configure apache 2.2 so it limits the amount of connections from a address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mod_limitipconn(http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn.html).

If you use Linux try iptables connlimit modules. If you use FreeBSD try ipfw limit state.